# how to change the size of a number before the decimal point with DecimalFormat method

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, decimalformat

how to limit the number of digits of the whole number itself not just the fractional part of the number after the decimal?

for example using the number 54321.12574857f with the method DecimalFormat("##0.##");  it should return 543.12 or 321.12,  the two decimal places after the decimal are correct however I want to reduce the numbers before the decimal to only 3.  how is this done?

after entering the number 54321.12574857 I was using the parameter for the DecimalFormat method of ##0.## and I was expecting 543.12, or 321.12 not what I am getting which is 54321.12

the only numbers changed by DecimalFormat method are those after the decimal

```
            float inputNumber = 54321.12574857f;

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##0.##");
    String newNumber = String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(inputNumber));

    System.out.println(newNumber);
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't use `%`?

Comment: can you give example of String.format using % ?  i assume you are talking about String.format method when you mentioned %

Comment: Nope.. I meant using `mod` operator.

Comment: Since you said "I was expecting 543.12, or **321.12**", you can do this `decimalFormat.format(inputNumber % 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this,

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##0.##");
    String newNumber = String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(inputNumber/100));
```

Comment: that would work, the only problem is that a method would have to be made to divide the number by how many digits oversized it is.  for example now it is 2 over so you would divide by 100 and for 3 over by 1000 then i would need a switch statement of if else to keep checking how many over.

Comment: @Kevik other wise you may not able to remove leading numbers by in this way.